# I am creating a module like Google Calendar's day view in my app

Tags: kotlin, android-listview, calendar, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

Creating a module like Google Calendar's day view in my app. In this app, I can select a time from a time slot. One slot = 30 minutes. Then, the user can drag that slot up and down and the selected time will be updated automatically and can also stretch the item to increase the selected time.

I tried it by indexes but the problem occurs when a user stretches the item because on that the two items get combined. How can I achieve such functionality?

#calendar #jetpackCompose #android

[image]